# MySQL order table by taking the sum of one colomn for groups of values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database of student exam data similar to the database displayed below. I am trying to assign `ranks` to these students by taking the sum of `Marks` of all subjects(`Subj`) for a semester(`Sem`) and sorting them accordingly.

So if this is the raw db:

```
    Name | S.NO.| Subj | Sem | Marks | Rank
    ab   |  B1  |  C1  | 1   |  002  | 
    ab   |  B1  |  C2  | 1   |  004  | 
    ab   |  B1  |  C3  | 1   |  005  | 
    ab   |  B1  |  C4  | 2   |  008  |  

    xy   |  C2  |  C1  | 1   |  006  |   
    xy   |  C2  |  C2  | 1   |  004  |  
    xy   |  C2  |  C3  | 2   |  007  | 
    xy   |  C2  |  C4  | 2   |  009  | 
    xy   |  C2  |  C5  | 2   |  003  |  

    sm   |  Z1  |  C1  | 1   |  006  | 
    sm   |  Z1  |  C2  | 2   |  004  |  
    sm   |  Z1  |  C3  | 2   |  008  |
```

I would like to convert it into:

```
    Name | S.NO.| Subj | Sem | Marks | Rank
    ab   |  B1  |  C1  | 1   |  002  |   1(coz his total is 11 in sem 1)
    ab   |  B1  |  C2  | 1   |  004  |   1
    ab   |  B1  |  C3  | 1   |  005  |   1

    ab   |  B1  |  C4  | 2   |  008  |   3

    xy   |  C2  |  C1  | 1   |  006  |   2
    xy   |  C2  |  C2  | 1   |  004  |   2

    xy   |  C2  |  C3  | 2   |  007  |   1(coz his total is 19 in Sem 2)
    xy   |  C2  |  C4  | 2   |  009  |   1
    xy   |  C2  |  C5  | 2   |  003  |   1

    sm   |  Z1  |  C1  | 1   |  006  |   3

    sm   |  Z1  |  C2  | 2   |  004  |   2
    sm   |  Z1  |  C3  | 2   |  008  |   2
```

The database has about 300k rows.

Comment: custom RANK OVER is heavy to implement in MySQL and it wont scale on large tables... how large will your tables become?

Comment: Why not have another table, with just a student name (or number), semester and a sum of marks?

Comment: It's a godaddy account with 300-500k rows its really difficult to do so as it'll give me a connection timeout error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want

```
select name,sno,subj,sem,mark,rank
from
(
select  e1.*
       , @sm:=(select sum(e2.mark) from exams e2 where e1.name=e2.name and e1.sem=e2.sem) summark
       , case when @sem!=sem then @r:=1 
              when @s  !=@sm then @r:=@r+1 
                             else @r 
         end as rank
       , @s:=@sm
       , @sem:=sem
       from exams e1,(select @r:=0, @s:=0,@sm:=0,@sem:=0) r
order by sem,summark desc
) r2      
order by sno,subj;
```

I do not know about the runtime. It maybe takes bit.

Demo on SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0290/1

To explain a bit the above. MySQL does not have analytical functions like other databases (e.g. Oracle). But the above simulates it. `@sm`is the sum of the marks. `@r` is the rank variable. It is increased if the marks sum changes. It is reset to 1 when semester changes. `@s` saves the sum of previous row and `@sem` saves the semester of the previous row.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment..javascript was blocked in my comp..took a while to make it work...about the code: AMAZING

Comment: and about the time..it takes a bit of time, but when I'm creating a new table with it it takes just a fraction of the time. Again THANKS A LOT